# How to know if a timer is cleared or timed out in javascript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Ok, really simple question. I'm taking a crash course in javascript.

If I use 
`timer = setTimeout(..., 500)` to set a timer, and then `clearTimeout(timer)` to clear the timer, the integer value of timer doesn't change, so my question is how to know if a timer is timed out or cleared?

I want to use `if (timer) {...}` , but obviously a positive integer always returns true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're looking for something more formal, you could build javascript class that encapsulates the `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` functionality.

Such a class might look something like this:

```
/** class Timer **/
var Timer = function(delayMs, callbackFunc) {
    this.delayMs = delayMs;
    this.callbackFunc = callbackFunc;
    this.timerState = 'new';
}
Timer.prototype.start = function() {
    if( this.tmr ) return;

    var self = this;
    this.timerState = 'running';
    this.tmr = setTimeout(function() { self._handleTmr(); }, this.delayMs);
}
Timer.prototype.cancel = function() {
    if( ! this.tmr ) return;

    clearTimeout(this.tmr);
    this.tmr = null;
    this.timerState = 'canceled';
}
Timer.prototype._handleTmr = function() {
    this.tmr = null;
    this.timerState = 'completed';
    this.callbackFunc();
}
```

I've also included a `timerState` attribute that would let you easily determine whether the timer was "completed" or "canceled".

You would use it like this:

```
var t = new Timer(500, function() {
    alert('timer completed');
});
t.start();

// do whatever...

// now cancel the timer if it hasn't completed yet.
t.cancel();

// maybe you do some other stuff...
// then check the timerState, and act accordingly.
//
if( t.timerState == 'canceled' ) {
   alert("the timer was canceled!");
} else {
   alert("the timer completed uneventfully.");
}
```

You can extend the same basic idea to include additional functionality if you need it (eg. repeating timer, start/stop/resume, etc.)

Comment: I would not be surprised at all if jQuery or one of the other JS frameworks had something like this. Any jQuery experts know if it exists or not?

Comment: This is really comprehensive. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

assign `null` to the timer after the `clearTimeout(timer)`

Comment: This is what I'm using now. It seems like a afterthought in Javascript. Any better ways to handle this?

Comment: not that I know of, sorry :S I think handles in Win32 behaved the same :)

Answer (score 0):

If you clear the timeout the callback won't be executed. So if the callback is executed it means that 500ms have passed since you've set the timeout.

For example:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    alert('you will never see this alert');
}, 500);
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I use for timer events! Hope this helps.

```
    var toggleTimeOut   = (function () {

    var _timeout;

    return function (clear_timeout) {

      if(!clear_timeout) 
      {
        _timeout    =   setTimeout( function () {/*DO YOUR STUFF*/}, 5000);
      }
      else
      {
        if(typeof _timeout != typeof undefined && _timeout != 0)
        {
            clearTimeout(_timeout);
            _timeout= 0;
        }
      }
    }
  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

I avoid using flags in JS in general but this is a case where it makes sense and keeps things nice and simple.  The idea is you set a flag once your timer has fired and then you can examine *that* elsewhere in code.

```js
let fired = false;

// Set your timeout to do future work...
const timeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
    fired = true;
    // ...
}, 3000);

// Test it
const testInterval = window.setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`Timer has ${fired ? ' ' : 'not '}fired`);
    fired && window.clearInterval(testInterval);
}, 500);
```