# How to overwrite setTimeout before it reach the time set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

So I'm doing an autocomplete search using jquery. I have to set a delay before executing the ajax function because I don't want to hammer my server with calls every time I type on a textbox. Here is my code:

```
function searchVendor() {
  setTimeout(searchVendor2, 5000);
}

function searchVendor2() {
  var search = $('#inputVendor').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/getVendors',
    data: {search: search},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(s) {
      $('#inputVendor').autocomplete({source: s});
    }
  });
}
```

so the function `searchVendor` is executed `onkeyup`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputVendor" onkeyup="searchVendor()">
```

If I type 3 characters (ex. sas) then the function `searchVendor2` is executed 3 times. The 5 seconds delay works but it didn't stop and overwrite the previous `setTimeout`.

What I want to happen is, if I type a character on the textbox it will be executed after 5 seconds, BUT! if a new character is typed before the 5 seconds, `setTimeout` is reset again to 5 seconds. As long as the user is typing on the textbox the `setTimeout` is reset to 5 seconds and it will ONLY be executed if the 5 seconds elapsed without the user typing again.

Thanks to those who can help!

Comment: you can give `minLength` option so that the search will take place only after user enters minimum chars. EG: `minLength: 3`

Comment: I'm not sure of I can say this but doesn't this defeat the autocomplete purpose? I think it would be better to use the feature given with the autocomplete such min length.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to save your timeout id in a global variable, or in a variable that can be accessed later when the function is called again.

Now, whenever your function is called, first you clear that timeout if it exists. Thus you clear any pre-existing timeouts and set a new one every time the function is called.

```
var myTimeout;

function searchVendor() {
  clearTimeout(myTimeout);
  myTimeout = setTimeout(searchVendor2, 5000);
}

function searchVendor2() {
  var search = $('#inputVendor').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/getVendors',
    data: {search: search},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(s) {
      $('#inputVendor').autocomplete({source: s});
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: since first will be undefined `if (myTimeout) {clearTimeout(myTimeout)}`

Comment: @NightKn8 it's not worth putting it in an `if` check. `clearTimeout()` ignores `undefined` and other non-existent timer IDs. And there is no notable performance cost.

Comment: @SethHolladay Yes you are correct, [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442183/javascript-is-it-ok-to-call-cleartimeout-before-settimeout). This would be useful in case of _edge cases_ mentioned in my above Link by `zzzzBov` But in this case it is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers involving `setTimeout()` are simple and will work, but this is one of the few times when I would recommend using a utility library as they can go a few steps further in a way that is noticeable to the user.

It is also important that we avoid re-inventing the wheel. And in this case, what you want is a *debounce* or *throttle* function to limit the number of times your handler gets executed within a given time span. The good libraries also accept options to tweak when exactly your handler gets run, which can affect the responsiveness of your app.

[Read more about debouncing and throttling](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

For your use case, I would recommend Lodash's `_.throttle()` with both `leading` and `trailing` options set to `true`. This will ensure that long entries of text will still get some intermediate results, while also getting results as fast as possible (not having to wait for a timer the first time around) and still guaranteeing that the final keystroke will trigger a new result, which not all debounce settings would do.

```
const handler = (evt) => {
    console.log('I will talk to the server.');
};

const throttled = _.throttle(handler, 500, {
    leading  : true,
    trailing : true
});
```

Then register the throttled function as the event listener.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputVendor" onkeyup="throttled()">
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the info. I think my codes run like a debounce.

Answer (score 1):

You must clear the timeout when you want to stop it.  Instead of just doing this:

```
var timeoutId;
function searchVendor() {
  timeoutId = setTimeout(searchVendor2, 5000);
}
```

you should add `clearTimeout(timeoutId);`, like this:

```
var timeoutId;
function searchVendor() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  timeoutId = setTimeout(searchVendor2, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minLength` of `autocomplete` so that the API is not called as soon as the user starts typing.

[Here is the reference from autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength)

**minLength:** The minimum number of characters a user must type before a search is performed

```
$( "#inputVendor" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 3
});
```

If you want on every keypress, as other answers suggested, you can use `clearTimeout` to remove the old timeout.

```
var timeout;

function searchVendor() {
   clearTimeout(timeout);
   timeout = setTimeout(searchVendor2, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions can be stopped using `clearTimeout` or `clearInterval` functions, passing the unique identifier generated by the first ones. For example, here you have a small code that helps you to understand this:

```
var delay;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
    callSetTimeout();
});

function callSetTimeout () {

    if (!isNaN(delay)) { clearTimeout(delay); }

    delay = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("do something");
    }, 5000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the timeout but I check with interval

```
var goal={
    cb: cb
,   timeout: (+new Date())+60000 //one minute from now
,   setInterval(function(){
        if((+new Date())>goal.timeout){cb();}
        })
    };
```

Now I want to increase, decrease or reset the timeout?

```
goal.timeout-=1000;
goal.timeout+=1000;
goal.timeout=60000;
```