# clearTimeout isn't clearing the timeout

Tags: javascript

Trying to clear a timeout and its not working.  console.logging it returns a number after its been initialized and after it's been destroyed.

```js
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {});
    console.log('initialised', timer); // initialised 22
    clearTimeout(timer);
    console.log('destroyed', timer); // destroyed 22
```

I'm expecting the second log to return null.  I also didn't expect the timer to be a simple number.  I would have expected it to be an object.  Is clearTimeout doing what it should be doing here?

Comment: You're doing it right. The variable won't change in value. If you need to detect when a timer is running, get/set a boolean when you create/destroy your timer. Kinda confusing, but that's JavaScript.

Comment: Bonus reading: that weird value is the [ID of the timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Return_value). Also [see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226749/2535504).

Comment: A function call like `clearTimeout(timer)` **cannot** change the `timer` variable. JS doesn't have pass-by-reference calls.

Comment: even if clearTimeout changed the value you have it `const`, which for primitives means they can't change values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `timer` variable holds a unique number that represents a particular timer. Clearing the timer stops the asynchronous operation, but your variable is still just that, a variable, and it will hold the last value you gave it unless  it goes out of scope or your assign something else to it.

The best proof that your code is working as it should is to give the timer callback function some behavior and see if that behavior is correct. With your code, we'll see that the timer callback function never actually runs (no message from the callback function is ever written to the console) because you are cancelling it before the function that created it completes. We don't need extra `console.log()` statements beyond that one.

```js
const timer = setTimeout(() => { console.log("The timer function has run!" ); });
clearTimeout(timer);
```

**NOTE:** In most cases, we don't need to know the actual value of the `timer` variable. We only need to store it to kill its corresponding timer operation later.

Answer (score 0):

[clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) is doing exactly what is expected of it. When you create a timeout, it returns a unique number, in your case you saved it in "timer" variable. Now when you clear timeout it just stops the setTimeout execution, but does not remove variable "timer"

Answer (score 0):

> I'm expecting the second log to return null.

The `timer` is a simple variable holding a number (ID of the timer). Doing `clearTimeout` does not change its value, but *clears a timeout*, i.e. stops the timer.

> I would have expected it to be an object

Why though? There is nothing to store in it. It is a simple number, starting from 1 for a very first timer, 2 for a second one, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand the return value of these functions.

> The returned `timeoutID` is a positive integer value which identifies
>   the timer created by the call to `setTimeout();`
>
> This value can be passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout.

It is guaranteed that the `setTimeout()` will always return an ID (number) not an object.

> The return value of `clearTimeout()` is `undefined`.

Also, I would like to add one more point, in Javascript the type `number` is always passed by value. So, you shouldn't be expecting it to change while you just pass it to a function. Like in your case,

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

An invocation like this can never change the value(at source) of the variable(type `number`) passed.

Answer (score -1):

`setTimeout` defines a timer and returns a number that is the unique id of that timer.
`clearTimeout` gets a timer id and cancels it.

Since number values in JavaScript are immutable and you are basically sending the `timer` variable's value to the `clearTimeout` function, the language, or the browser, cannot change the value of the variable, hence the number will not change in the scope of your function, and the result is that you still see the same number in both logs.

It does, however, cancels the timeout, so that the call to the function you sent to `setTimeout` will not be called, as long as you called `clearTimeout` before it was called.

Here is more information about [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [clearTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp).

Comment: *Since numbers in JavaScript are immutable, the language, or the browser, cannot change the value of the number, hence the number will not change, and this is why you still see both logs.* Well, no. Primitives may be immutable, but variables aren't. The reason you see the number is not because numbers are immutable, it's because the variable hasn't gone out of scope and the value that the variable is storing hasn't been replaced with anything else.

Comment: immutable? `var n=1; n++; alert(n);`

Comment: @Scott Marcus - I might have not explained myself the best way possible. But the intent was the same. @dandavis - well, `n++` is equivalent to `n=n+1` which is an assignment. I don't understand what you are trying to show here. The number primitive value is still immutable, as I said.

Comment: I suspected that your intent was correct, but the explanation is incorrect and it's important that it be corrected because what you are talking about is very different than the actual issue.

Comment: @Scott Marcus - I stand corrected and fixed my answer. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, but your updated answer is still off the mark. Immutability has nothing to do with this and the value of the variable (that is, the value that the variable holds) certainly can be changed (when the variable is declared with `var` or `let`). This is simply a matter of the `timer` variable not going out of scope and no code attempts to alter it, so it's value stays in memory and unchanged.