# clear timeout after the setTimeout callback execution

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Does this clear my timeout

```
  const timer1 = setTimeout(()=> {
            setSuccessMessage('')
            clearTimeout(timer1)
        },3000);
```

The code execute well, but I need to know if the timer is cleared at the end.
I've tested a solution given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226578/check-if-a-timeout-has-been-cleared) but the timer get cleared before my stuff get finished, and considering that my timeout is intended to hide a message, the former remains displayed because the timer got cleared.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to cancel your timer here as it is automatically garbage collected after it is executed.

You do need to cancel it only if you ever intend to cancel it BEFORE it is fired, which is not your case.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)